# SignalR client server application with self hosted

Tags: c#, wcf, service, signalr, messaging

I am developing application using signalr. One application is server application (self host ) which is desktop application and run on server another application, I am going to develop wcf service (signalr self host) but when I run that application it gives me error

StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
Date: Tue, 27 Jul 2021 12:06:52 GMT
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Content-Length: 0
}

the wcf service is not connecting  to the server application (self host signalr)

Answer (score 0):

In general, Http 500 errors are server-side problems. You can check the server-side network connection and try to debug your Web service.

Thanks.

Comment: My wcf service and signalr server application are both on same machine. wcf service hosted in iis.

Comment: Try : Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager —> Default Web Site —> Click Error Pages properties and select Detail errors.

Comment: And the link below you can refer to : https://winzikha.weebly.com/blog/step-by-step-create-chat-application-that-demonstrates-signalr